# Removing the hops after the boil when no chilling

Tags: hops, hop-utilization, no-chill

The biggest objection to no chill brewing I have heard so far was that the extended content time of the hops with the wort will create off flavors and add IBUs.
When I boil my wort I usually put the hops in a straining bag so I won't have to filter it later. 
Does removing the begs after the boil, and then let it cool naturally negates the aforementioned effect?

Comment: No,you want to remove the Hopps after the boil.Also you Hopps you use for aroma you will take out at the same time. Hope this helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No chill, slow chill = more IBU from late hop additions**

No chill concerns for hops is late additions will continue to isomerize until below 175°F.

Removing the hops will help, but any alpha acids already released in the wort will continue to isomerize.

Some recent studies show that 175°F isn't like a switch, but temperature and time follow a curve for alpha acid to iso-alpha acid conversion. Even as low as 145°F has 5-10% conversion over 30-60 minutes.

Any hop additions boiled for 45min or more would already be fully converted and not effected by a slow chill.

No chill or slow chill isn't for all beer styles.

Example: Consider this hypothetical recipe with same AA hops for both bitter and aroma additions.
 *Target IBU 80, 5oz boil addition, 5oz flame out.*
When chilled quick reaches 80 IBU. When chilled slow taking more than 10 hours to reach below 145°F could reach 160 IBU.

Answer (score 2):

You should be fine.

I always boil the hops normally (without a bag), then filter the boiling hot wort through cheese cloth to get the hops and protein out. After that the still very hot wort goes in a closed fermenting bucket and stays on the counter over night to get to pitching temperatures.

This works fine, but don't try to let unfermented wort sit for a couple of days; chances are too big to catch a contamination.